# What is the diffrence between design Pattern and Framework?

Tags: design-patterns, frameworks

Is their any difference between design pattern and Framework, Some time people say MVC Design pattern and some time MVC Framework. Is both are same thing?

Comment: Just lookup the definition of [Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) and [Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) and you'll understand the differences.

Answer (score 4):

Design patterns and frameworks are two completely different things.

MVC is a design pattern. "MVC frameworks" is shortcut for "frameworks that follow MVC design pattern".

Comment: What do you mean, one place both are different thing and another place MVC is design pattern as well framework

Comment: They are not completely different things. For example the Factory Method Pattern is a design pattern and if you look at the UML diagram also describes a framework. Criteria for it being a framework comprise providing extension points (hooks), inversion of control, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The terms Pattern, Design Pattern and Framework are most often used interchangeably. However, these terms are not identical and there is a logical difference among their definitions. Here it goes:

Pattern:

A pattern is a way of doing something, or a way of pursuing intent. This idea applies to cooking, making fireworks, developing software, and to any other craft. It is a solution to a problem in a context. Patterns are classified into 1) Design Pattern, 2) Architectural Pattern, 3) Macro – Architecture, 4) Micro – Architecture, 5) Idioms or Coding Patterns, 6) Language Paradigms etc.

Design Pattern:

Design pattern is a category of patterns that deals with object oriented software. They represent solutions to problems that arise when developing software within a particular context. Design pattern captures the static and dynamic structure and collaboration among key participants in software designs. They can be used across different domains.

Framework:

Framework is made up of group of concrete classes which can be directly implemented on an existing platform. Frameworks are written in programming languages. It is a large entity comprising of several design patterns. Frameworks are concerned with specific application domain e.g. database, web application etc.

Above definition very much clarifies the difference among three. A design pattern is a type of pattern and is more like a concept, whereas a framework is something already coded to be used repetitively.

Hope you find this information useful.

Comment: `It is a large entity comprising of several design patterns` I would have to disagree. A framework is **comprised** of classes, methods functions, etc. That is it is comprised of code. That code may, or may not, **follow** a design pattern.

Comment: MVC is not written any language its a standard